# Magento : Get Sub-Categories and 8 Products From Each Sub-Category

Tags: magento-1.9, product, category, filter, category-products

I want to make a landing page for Magento 1.9.3.4. What I got is the following:

Head category: Computer

Sub-categories from Computer: Harddisk, Monitor, Cables, Keyboards.

I want to make a page for "Computer" where all the sub-categories will be shown and 8 products from each sub-category.

How can I do this in best way?

Answer (score 0):

I got it:

```
<?php $_helper = Mage::helper('catalog/category') ?>
<?php $categoryId = 48;?>
<?php $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId) ?>
<?php $_categories = $category->getChildrenCategories() ?>

<?php if (count($_categories) > 0): ?>
    <?php foreach($_categories as $_category): ?>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="container">
                <a href="<?php echo $_helper->getCategoryUrl($_category) ?>"><?php echo $_category->getName() ?></a>
                <?php
                    $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_category->getId());
                    $_productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
                        ->addCategoryFilter($_category)
                        ->addAttributeToSelect('*');
                ?>
                <ul class="products-grid row-4">
                    <?php $i = 0; foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): $i++; ?>
                        <?php $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId()) ?>

                        <li class="item col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
                            <div class="product-content">
                                <div class="product-top">
                                    <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true) ?>" class="product-image">
                                        <?php $productImage = $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize($size['width'], $size['height']); ?>
                                        <?php $productImageHover = $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'thumbnail')->resize($size['width'], $size['height']); ?>
                                        <?php if(!$lazyLoad): ?>
                                            <?php $baseImg = $productImage; $baseImgHover = $productImageHover; ?>
                                        <?php endif ?>
                                        <img id="product-collection-image-<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>" src="<?php echo $baseImg ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true) ?>" class="img-responsive<?php if($lazyLoad): ?> lazy<?php endif ?>" data-original="<?php echo $productImage ?>"/>

                                        <?php if(basename($_product->getData('thumbnail')) != basename($_product->getData('small_image'))): ?>
                                            <img src="<?php echo $baseImgHover ?>"
                                            alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true) ?>" class="img-responsive img-hover<?php if($lazyLoad): ?> lazy<?php endif ?>" data-original="<?php echo $productImage ?>"/>
                                        <?php endif ?>
                                    </a>

                                    <div class="add-to-cart">
                                        <?php if ($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                                            <?php if ($_product->getTypeInstance(true)->hasRequiredOptions($_product) || $_product->isGrouped()): ?>
                                                <button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" class="btn btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>')"><span class="icon pe-7s-shopbag"></span><span class="text"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart'); ?></span></button>
                                            <?php else: ?>
                                                <button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" class="btn btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>')"><span class="icon pe-7s-shopbag"></span><span class="text"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart'); ?></span></button>
                                            <?php endif; ?>
                                        <?php else: ?>
                                            <p><?php echo $this->__('Our of stock') ?></p>
                                        <?php endif; ?>
                                    </div>

                                </div>

                                <div class="product-desc">
                                    <h5 class="product-name">
                                        <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true) ?>"><?php echo $this->helper('catalog/output')->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName() , 'name') ?></a>
                                    </h5>
                                    <p class="bk-product-short-description">
                                        <?php echo substr($_product->getShortDescription(),0,40).'...'; ?>
                                    </p>
                                    <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true, '-widget-new-grid') ?>
                                    <?php
                                        if ($this->getChild('name.after')) {
                                            $_nameAfterChildren = $this->getChild('name.after')->getSortedChildren();
                                            foreach ($_nameAfterChildren as $_nameAfterChildName) {
                                                $_nameAfterChild = $this->getChild('name.after')->getChild($_nameAfterChildName);
                                                $_nameAfterChild->setProduct($_product);
                                                echo $_nameAfterChild->toHtml();
                                            }
                                        }
                                    ?>

                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </li>
                    <?php endforeach ?>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```